# Is there any way to make generic implementation in delete duplicate values in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, koala

I am trying this code but need generic implementation of deleting duplicates in dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

# making data frame from csv file
data = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/gvsph/Downloads/employees.csv")

# sorting by first name
data.sort_values("First Name", inplace=True)

# dropping ALL duplicte values
data.drop_duplicates(subset="First Name",
                     keep=False, inplace=True)

# displaying data
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'drop_duplicates' without parameters to remove all duplicate records from your dataset.

cfr [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)